# Pass variable value from Geojson file to filter another Geojson layer Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have an leaflet map with 2 geojson file loaded locally using the leaflet ajax filter.
I am trying to filter the second geojson (polyline) based on 'click' of any of the first geojson point feature. both of them had the same SiteID field
I am able to get the feature ID,

```
           layer.on("click", function(e){ 
                 pollid= feature.properties.SiteID; // ID from first layer geojson


                 console.log(pollid);

                lyrSpider.addTo(map); // second geojson file 
                console.log(pollid);
            });
```

how can I pass the (pollid)  to filter the second geojson

```
 function spiderfilter(feature) {


            if (feature.properties.SiteID == pollid) return true; // problem,
        }
```

I could not figure out the variable scope. here.

Comment: "I solved it by just removing the geojson layer if its exist. if(map.hasLayer(lyrSpider)){ lyrSpider.remove(); }" I couldn't able to achieve this function.. Any samples please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can create lyrSpider inside of the first function you showed, then you can set the *filter* option during creation like this:

```
layer.on("click", function(e){ 
    let pollid = feature.properties.SiteID;

    let lyrSpider = L.geoJSON(geoJSON_data, {
        filter: function(feature, layer) {
            if (pollid == feature.properties.SiteID) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    lyrSpider.addTo(map);
});
```

See the L.geoJSON docs: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson-filter.

Comment: Thank you, that was a fantastic solution so far, how can I remove the filter on the second click, , Thanks

Comment: I don't know the context, but you could create a global variable (_clicked_) set to (_false_), add (_&& clicked == false_) to the condition, and then inside the filter, after the if-statement, set (_clicked_) to (_true_). So, after the first click, it will filter no more.

Comment: Thank you, Actually I don't need to stop the filter I need to update the filter by clicking another point in my first layer, and remove the old filter results.

Comment: how can I update the filter (re filter by adding new one and removing previous one.

Comment: Maybe just create a new L.geoJSON object with the new one?

Comment: where should I create a new L.geoJSON object according the code you provided before.

Comment: I solved it by just removing the geojson layer if its exist. if(map.hasLayer(lyrSpider)){
                       lyrSpider.remove();
                    }.  thank you for your help